# Exception Handling : Getting different output in each run for same code

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally, try-finally

I am getting different output in each run of my program. When executed first time, it gives[image]

When executed again, it 
[image]
Please tell me why it is occurring.

```
public class TwoExcepProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            int a = 50/0;
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("finally block is called");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Took me a second to get there. Problem is that the two messages go to **two** different streams.

Comment: @GhostCat just to stay clear of any danger in the future, I didn't downvote your answer :)

Comment: @ChandlerBing Thanks for the information. But dont you worry. I absolutely hate **revenge** downvoters. I maybe do sometimes things that are not 100% according to the strict rules here; but I never ever downvote content because I had "issues" with another users. Downvotes go out for content I disapprove with; for nothing else.

Comment: And finally, to address your comment: execution order is try block, catch block, finally block. Exactly in that order. As it is written down in any book or tutorial for this topic.

Answer (score 3):

You let propagate an exception that makes your program crashed.

In these conditions, you should not expect to have a gracious and rigorous order appearing of the output of the exception that has stopped the program (output written by the `System.err.println()` method) and the output written in the `finally`  statement (output written by the `System.out.println()` method) since these are two distinct streams not necessarily flushed at the same time.

You should handle the exception to prevent this behavior :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int a = 50 / 0;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        // exception handling
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("finally block is called");
    }
}
```

Comment: DV, because the explanation is wrong. The fact that OP uses an exception doesn't matter here. The issue is _solely_ based on the fact that OP writes to two different streams which are independently flushed.

Comment: You can test this with a simple `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { System.out.println(i); System.err.println(i); }`.

Comment: Two down votes, waouh :) @Tom thank your for your fair :) It is not really right : the OP doesn't write to two different streams. He writes to a stream (System.out). The System.err writing is caused because he lets the exception crash the program.

Comment: Never mind. Good days, bad days. I only had  a single upvote today, so, whatever. You know what, you got your upvote back; trusting you to improve your question later on.

Comment: @Tom  The explanation was really not wrong. I had not just detailed these points. I updated it.

Comment: Oh yes, that's correct, he indirectly writes to "serr" due to the exception. Thanks for updating the answer.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for your kindness. You are the best :) Some days are sometimes not good indeed.

Comment: @Tom You are welcome. Anyway, you was right to alert me about these details that are important to give a better explanation.